# Wordpress multisite,one theme,and different languages?

Tags: multisite, localization

I'm not sure is this possible,for example I have english,french and italian blog,they all use same theme,I just want when visitor is on french site for example to display date,(some strings like search,next page,...) on French,can I do it with theme localization an how,how to setup wordpress multisite to use this theme localization?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://wpmututorials.com/how-to/localization/

Basically after you install the language packs, go to that site and change the language option from the admin area.

Comment: tnx,I just realize that no mater if you just want to tranlate theme and not backend you should have languages installed into wp-content folder,and not in theme folder.This doesn't make sense for me,because I just want to translate theme.Tnx any way,this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parts to your question:

for dates etc, you should have the wordpress translation files loaded  - then dates will be 'localised', so long as the theme or plugin uses http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n  (wordpress does, so if it is it's code it should be fine)

For any theme generated strings, then yes your theme must use the __() or _e() translation functions (any half way decent theme should have been written with this in mind) and have the necessary language files.

If no language files exist for the theme, it is easy to create them using a variety of tools (eg : code styling localisation plugin)

See
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_in_Your_Language
http://svn.automattic.com/wordpress-i18n/  (wp language file respository)

theme developer should know this:
http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Comment: Hi,tnx for the answer,this was useful,but how can I setup on multisite default blog to be on English,and other blog to use French,and other blog Italian,do I need several po and mo files,is there any tutorial how to handle this?

Comment: When I go on multisite settings,on edit on one blog,there is WPLANG option,but I can't change that?

Comment: Hi user1147, I think you may have to use a plugin to set the wplang then (wp will then look for those language files).  There are a number of options: http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/other-plugins/in-their-language/ will try to do it based on browser language and for backend there is also http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-native-dashboard/.     If you google language switching for wordpress, you will find a number of other options too: I don't know this one, but it sounds helpful: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multisite-language-switcher/

Answer (score -1):

There is special plugin for this, called [Quick Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-localization/). It is developed by my company.

You can patch any plugin or theme as long as they use `__()` and `_e()` functions properly.

Comment: And how does it work? So far it's only a link.